# Adding search function in Parse (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I want to provide the user the ability to search users within the database, and upon selection it would display various information about the user.

What I have brainstormed so far is the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");

    $('#userIDSearch').bind("submit", function (e) {

    });
</script>

<form id="userIDSearch">
    <input type="search" name="usersearch">
    <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

Not sure what to do next and would appreciate guidance. Thanks in advance.\

**Update:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");
    var currentUser = user;
    query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.userId);  // find user with this ID

    function searchu() {
        var user_search = $('#searchusertext').val();
        var query = new Parse.Query(User);
        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                // results is an array of Parse.Object.
            },

            error: function(error) {
                // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
            }
        });

      $('#userIDSearch').bind("submit", function (e) {

    });
</script>

<form id="userIDSearch">
    <input type="search" id="searchusertext" name="usersearch">
    <input type="submit" id="searchuserbutton" value="search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The next steps would be:

1. Execute a function when the search button is pressed.
2. The function should execute a Parse query with the search value passed into the query.
3. The results will then be used to populate your UI.

Let me know if that's not enough guidance.

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestions. I would kindly require more guidance, and for your courteously, I have included the updated code under my initial post.